# Can I sync players and worlds between multiple computers?

Tags: terraria

> This question was asked before Terraria supported syncing through Steam Cloud.

I want to play Terraria with the same players and worlds on two different computers. It looks like the files must be in `My Documents\My Games\Terraria`.

Is there a way to sync those files between two or more computers (using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [AeroFS](http://www.aerofs.com/) for example) so that when I play on one computer, the player and world files will automatically update on the other computer?

Comment: [The internet is full of non-game specific helpful information that might help](http://lifehacker.com/372175/free-ways-to-synchronize-folders-between-computers)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done with [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and a line in Command Prompt.

1. Quit Terraria to make sure none of the files are in use.
2. Look for the folder `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Games\Terraria` (this is the Windows Vista/7 location).
3. Move this folder into your Dropbox folder.
4. Open Command Prompt with administrative privileges by right-clicking on it in the Start menu and choosing "Run as administrator".
5. Run this command: `mklink /d "C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Games\Terraria" "C:\Users\<username>\Dropbox\Terraria"`
6. Launch Terraria and verify your characters and worlds are available.
7. Repeat steps 4 and 5 on each additional computer that you want your characters and worlds to be available on.

---

Another option, perhaps even simpler, is to use [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) to synchronize the Terraria folders on two computers. If you use BitTorrent Sync you do not have to move the folders and make links. You can sync them in-place.

Comment: Nice solution, but stop using dropbox. It has no client-side encryption.

Comment: @Tom I prefer to separate my client-side encryption and my file synchronization technologies.

Comment: Just tried this with Google Drive and this solution works great with that, too. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can also replace `C:\Users\<username>` with `%USERPROFILE%` to make it easier. `mklink /d "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria" "%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Terraria"`

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. So useful.

Comment: You can also skip the mklink entirely and use Bittorrent Sync, telling it to sync your Terraria directories directly.

Answer (score 2):

[GameSaveManager](http://www.gamesave-manager.com/) can detect game saves for hundreds of games. It supports easy moving of games through zip files. It also has support for syncing using Dropbox or your own Private FTP server.

Comment: Does this program even support Terraria otherwise your answer is useless.  **Besides Steam already supports this ability.**

Comment: @Ramhound Their site states that it supports both Terraria characters and worlds. Also what makes you think Steam supports this already? Terraria doesn't use Steam Cloud .

Answer (score 0):

[SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) lets you add specific folders to sync with other places. However I think the free version only allows two computers to be shared.

In addition, it does not change the folder in anyway and if you have a different path to sync with an the other computer that can also be set up.