# Where are my world files?

Tags: terraria

I want to transfer my world from my PC to a second PC, but I cannot find the `world` files.  Can you please help me?

Comment: You may be interested in [Can I sync players and worlds between multiple computers?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73445/9818)

Answer (score 30):

The `world` files should be located at

```
C:\Users\[your name]\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds
```

regardless of how you configure your system environment variables or Steam library.

Comment: It should be noted that this is the location regardless of how you configure your system environment variables or steam library.

Comment: The character files should be in the same location as well.

Answer (score 9):

On Mac, world and character files are at

```
~/Library/Application Support/Terraria/Worlds
~/Library/Application Support/Terraria/Players
```

On Linux, the directories are

```
~/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds
~/.local/share/Terraria/Players
```

If that doesn't work for Linux, try

```
$XDG_DATA_HOME/Terraria/Worlds
$XDG_DATA_HOME/Terraria/Players
```

Comment: The `~/Library` folder is hidden by default on Macs. See this question for instructions on how to see hidden files and folders on Macs: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder

Comment: Source for my answer: http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/

Answer (score 6):

Sorry if I'm bumping this post, but if anybody else is here, you can Move it to Cloud.

When you are on the worlds screen, (select a player first) you can click Move To Cloud on one of the worlds.
What that means, is that you can find that world on any computer that is using that Steam account.